# FedEx - Rates API - Invalid piece count

Tags: php, api, fedex

I am trying to get shipping rates for a package between two locations.
In the request array I have created the proper structure and provided NumberOfPieces in the proper place.

```
stdClass Object
(
    //OTHER ELEMENTS REDACTED HERE
    [RequestedShipment] => stdClass Object
    (
         [Commodities] => Array
                    (
                        [NumberOfPieces] => 1
                        [Description] => Dog Meat
                        [CountryOfManufacture] => US
                        [Weight] => Array
                            (
                                [Units] => LB
                                [Value] => 20
                            )

                        [Quantity] => 1
                        [QuantityUnits] => EA
                        [UnitPrice] => Array
                            (
                                [Currency] => USD
                                [Amount] => 20
                            )

                        [CustomsValue] => Array
                            (
                                [Currency] => USD
                                [Amount] => 100
                            )

                    )
```

Now, the issue is, the response from the API says that I have entered invalid piece count.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Severity] => ERROR
            [Source] => crs
            [Code] => 546
            [Message] => Invalid piece count. 
            [LocalizedMessage] => Invalid piece count. 
        )

    [Version] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ServiceId] => crs
            [Major] => 16
            [Intermediate] => 0
            [Minor] => 0
        )

)
```

I have tried scouring the web for possible solutions, but in vain. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up facing this same issue today. The shipment structure needs to have the Shipper and Recipient defined inside of RequestedShipment. The below allowed me to get the rates successfully:

```php
Array
(
    [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array(...)
    [ClientDetail] => Array(...)
    [Version] => Array(...)
    [RequestedShipment] => Array
        (
            [Shipper] => Array(...)
            [Recipient] => Array(...)
            [PackageCount] => 1
            [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array(...)
        )
)
```